# DatagridView not Showing Data on Databound to DataTable

Tags: winforms, datagridview

This is the code i written but i am unable to view the data what's wrong can any one tell

```
conn_obj.Connect();
        SQL = "SELECT FIELDNAME BS_FIELDF WHERE FK_TABDF = '";
        SQL = SQL + Table_pkey + "' ORDER BY FIELDNAME";
        dSet = conn_obj.SQL_Data_Retrieve(SQL.ToString(), "BS_FIELDF");
        conn_obj.DisConnect();
        MainTableGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;  // Added now....
        Bind_DataGridView.DataSource = dSet.Tables[0];
        MainTableGrid.DataSource = Bind_DataGridView.DataSource;
        MainTableGrid.Refresh();
        MainTableGrid.Parent.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting data back from your query?

If not add a comma between `FIELDNAME` and `BS_FIELDF` in your SQL statement.